# How to eliminate newlines in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to use ERB with a plain text file. Here's the content of the plain text file:

```
<% if true %>
<%= 'bar' %>
<% end %>
<%= 'foo' %>
<%= 'bar' %>
```

The result I get with ERB is:

```
bar

foo
bar
```

The result I want to get is:

```
bar
foo
bar
```

without the empty newlines before "bar" and "foo".

Now, I know this is because ERB is configured (by default) to work with HTML files. What I want it to do is work with a plain text file in my case. I'm aware this is "somehow" possible because in Rails, when you work with Rails mailer to configure a plain text file, this doesn't happen.

Here's the big picture of what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to write a plain text article, but have some Ruby code in-between. I figured I'd use ERB for this, but the first stumbling block I got was this.

Comment: Did you try with the default trim mode `<% whatever -%>`? You may need to create your template handler with the appropriate param as well.

Answer (score 4):

In it's default mode, ERB treats the text very literally outside of the `<% ... %>` expressions. So think of your text as being a stream that looks like this:

```
<% if true %><LF><%= 'bar' %><LF><% end %><LF><%= 'foo' %><LF><%= 'bar' %><LF>
```

As you can see, you'll get a line feed before "bar" and two line feeds before "foo". *I.e.*, the output will be:

```
<blank line>
bar
<blank line>
foo
bar
```

The way around it is to use the "trim mode" option for `erb`. Write your file as:

```
<% if true -%>
<%= 'bar' %>
<% end -%>
<%= 'foo' %>
<%= 'bar' %>
```

Then call `erb -T - your_erb_file.erb`

```
bar
foo
bar
```

The `-T -` tells `erb` to remove the end of line if the line ends with `-%>`. Leading whitespaces are removed if the `erb` directive starts with `<%-`. See, for example, this [manual page for `erb`](https://www.mankier.com/1/erb) for details.